# Why my code is not saving data using shared preferences?

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to save the state of a Number Text View but is not working. At first I was thinking that the app was not reading my data because I copy the code from the oficial documentation. But after investigate a little more I look in android/data/ and there was not a folder called sad.whyIsNot.Saving, I tried many tutorials on youtube but I do not know why I am doing wrong. Can some one of you guys explain to me what is happening and how can I solve it?

This is the code for my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vplayeras1"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/valorDefectoVeces"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/agrega1"
        android:layout_width="149dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/playera1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code of my MainActivity.

```
package sad.whyIsNot.Saving

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        loadData()
        val btnPlayera1: Button = findViewById(R.id.agrega1)
        btnPlayera1.setOnClickListener{aumenta1()}
    }

    private fun loadData(){
        val sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val valPlayera1 = sharedPref.getInt("VECES_PLAYERA1", 0)
    }

    private fun aumenta1() {
        val resultText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.vplayeras1)
        val resultInt = resultText.text.toString().toInt() + 1
        resultText.text = resultInt.toString()
        val sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        with (sharedPref.edit()) {
            putInt("VECES_PLAYERA1", resultInt)
            commit()
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"Se ha guardado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: `val valPlayera1 = sharedPref.getInt("VECES_PLAYERA1", 0)` You are doing nothing with val valPlayera1 so how can you say that nothing is readed?

Comment: `I look in android/data/ and there was not a folder called sad.whyIsNot.Saving` Why would there be such a foldet? Makes no sense.

Comment: It is unclear why you think your data is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, I assume you know that loadData doesn't do anything with the data and you already tested if you have access to it?

Accessing the preferences outside of MainActivity might not work because getPreferences is bound to a specific activity.

If aumenta1 doesn't return I doubt that the value isn't put inside of the File, so I'd rather check if resultInt isn't 0 and that loadData really can't access the value